# Login Authentication with Requests

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to work with requests (python 3.4) to create a session where I log into gamefaqs.com and navigate to a board page so that I can scrape the content off to get relavant information for what I'm trying to accomplish. I directly copied the header and payload information from the developer console in firefox.

```
import requests
import urllib3

url = 'http://www.gamefaqs.com/user/login'
url2 = 'http://www.gamefaqs.com/user/Leight_Weight/boards'

header = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
    'Referer': 'http://www.gamefaqs.com/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'www.gamefaqs.com',
    }

payload = {
    'path': "http://www.gamefaqs.com/",
    'key': "71548de4",
    'EMAILADDR': "username",
    'PASSWORD': "password",
    }

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.get(url, headers=header)
    p = s.post(url, headers=header, data=payload, cookies = s.cookies)
```

The problem that I'm having is that I'm not receiving back the authentication cookie passed from the website to my session. I'm using fiddler to track the post request from Python. Despite the request header information being identical to the request header information in firefox, the response header information is very different.

The response header from firefox (as seen by Fiddler):
[Firefox Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3XDk.png)

The response header from Python (as seen by Fiddler):
[Python Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL7rY.png)

At this point I'm at a bit of a loss. As far as I can tell my code is sound and the request headers are correct, however not receiving the authentication cookie proves something is wrong. If you look in the response header the codes are different (302 vs 200). I'm not sure what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out - the payload item 'key' changes depending on your session. I didn't catch this initially because I didn't think of the fact that browsers use persistent cookies through open/close, something this solution does not use.

I did a bit of a heavy-handed approach to finding the right key value using BeautifulSoup, but the result remains the same. Once I had the appropriate key value, I added that to the payload before doing the post command and viola - successful login.

For posterity's sake, the code is below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'http://www.gamefaqs.com/user/login'
url2 = 'http://www.gamefaqs.com/user/Leight_Weight/boards'

header = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
    'Referer': 'http://www.gamefaqs.com/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'www.gamefaqs.com',
    }

payload = {
    'PASSWORD': "password",
    'path': "http://www.gamefaqs.com/",
    'EMAILADDR': "username",
    }

with requests.Session() as s:
    resp = s.get(url, headers=header)
    parse = bs(resp.text)
    keyval = parse.find_all('form')[1].contents[1]['value']
    payload['key'] = keyval
    p = s.post(url, headers=header, data=payload)
```